# 'SendGridMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Text' or 'Html' in .net mvc and SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sendgrid

Im trying to integrate SendGrid in ASP.NET MVC project but got stuck while following the tutorial in the Microsoft page.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new EmailAddress(
                            "Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S.");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text =  message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I put this code to App_Start folder with the name of `IdentitiyConfig.cs` but I get these two error messages:

> - 'SendGridMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type
>     'SendGridMessage'
> - 'SendGridMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Html' and no extension method 'Html' accepting a first argument of type
>     'SendGridMessage'

for the lines :

```
    myMessage.Text =  message.Body;
    myMessage.Html = message.Body;
```

I include these libraries:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using SendGrid;

using System.Net;

using System.Configuration;

using System.Diagnostics;

using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

using System.Web.UI;
```

I tried everything but couldnt come up with a solution. Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Seems like a version upgrade issue. Try this link - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/ExampleNet45Project/Example.cs

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
 myMessage.HtmlContent = message.Body;
```

this might solve.

Comment: use  
`myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
myMessage.HtmlContent = message.Body; `
instead of 
`myMessage.Text =  message.Body;
myMessage.Html = message.Body;`

or if you are using api V3 you can flow :
(https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/) @ Pierre.Vriens